# Windows .batch Choice command always chooses the same choice no matter input

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-choice

I'm doing a project to help myself learn batch a little better. I have code which is meant to be a "UI" of sorts.

The snippet I have an issue with is this:

```
:install_check
if exist UI (
echo UI is already installed; reinstall?
CHOICE
if Errorlevel 1 goto :del
if Errorlevel 2 goto :return
cls && goto :install_check
)
goto :install_yes
```

I know the naming conventions and some of the coding stuff isn't perfect, but I really see no reason why every time it runs it goes to `:del` no matter what I type in for `choice`.

I've changed the `choice` switches and moved it around to be all in one line but it still doesn't want to work. The `if` that it is nested in is meant to check if a file is present on the computer, so it is a requirement but also may be the issue?

I tried looking around on this site but nothing will help my issue, any help is gladly accepted!!

Comment: `choice /?` Read the last two lines before the examples. ( `if errorlevel x` means "if errorlevel is x *or greater*")

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Fixed my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `errorlevel`s in *reverse*-order.

```
if errorlevel n
```

means if `errorlevel` is n **or greater**

hence, `errorlevel` 2 will be interpreted as `true` for `if errorlevel 1`

Comment: @TommyStewart - When you can (there's a time limit) should Accept the answer that works for you by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

ERRORLEVEL doesn't update inside control blocks like IF statements unless you use !ERRORLEVEL! instead of %ERRORLEVEL% and use this command at the start of your code: setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

see http://batcheero.blogspot.ca/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html

Answer (score 0):

As a solution has already been determined, the following example, *(using your existing label names)*, restructures your code a little:

```bat
:install_check
ClS
If Not Exist "UI" GoTo install_yes
Choice /M "UI is already installed; reinstall"
If Errorlevel 2 GoTo return
GoTo del
```

*If the next line/label in your code is `:del`, you may also remove line six.

If the name `UI` belonged to a directory instead of a file then you'd change the third line to `If Not Exist "UI\" GoTo install_yes`.*